# Shorten URL using AliasMatch

Tags: regex, apache, mod-alias

I'm able to get the following configuration to work:-

```
Alias /webdoc /data/apps/jenkins/jobs

<Directory /data/apps/jenkins/jobs/[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+/workspace/target/docco>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

With this configuration, I can make the following URL work

```
http://myserver/webdoc/HCMS-JS/workspace/target/docco/horizontal/index.html
```

However, I want to shorten the URL to something like this:-

```
http://myserver/webdoc/HCMS-JS/horizontal/index.html
```

I tried the following configuration, but I keep getting 404 when trying to hit the above link:-

```
AliasMatch ^/webdoc/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/(.*) /data/apps/jenkins/jobs/$1/workspace/target/docco$2

<Directory /data/apps/jenkins/jobs/[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+/workspace/target/docco>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

How do I get this to work? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your AliasMatch lacks a slash:

```
AliasMatch ^/webdoc/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/(.*)
```

The first match here will be `HCMS-JS`. The second will be `horizontal/index.html`. That means that the result will be

```
/data/apps/jenkins/jobs/HCMS-JS/workspace/target/doccohorizontal/index.html
```

So you need to change the line to be

```
AliasMatch ^/webdoc/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/(.*) /data/apps/jenkins/jobs/$1/workspace/target/docco/$2
```

to insert the slash that you didn't capture.

A good first place to look for these kinds of problems is the apache error log. It should tell you what file it is that it can't find.